# What's the right way to pass a Variable as Reference to a class?

Tags: c++

I wonder what is the best way to pass a variable as a reference to a class. As far as i know there are three ways (maybe much more as i know C++).

Given the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Database {
    public:
        std::string name;
};

class ConsumeDatabase1 {
    public:
        ConsumeDatabase1(Database& database) : database_{database} {
            std::cout << &database << "\n";
        }
    private:
        Database& database_;
};

class ConsumeDatabase2 {
    public:
        ConsumeDatabase2(Database* database): database_{database} {
            std::cout << database << "\n";
        }

    private:
        Database* database_;
};

class ConsumeDatabase3 {
    public:
        ConsumeDatabase3(Database& database): database_{&database} {
            std::cout << &database << "\n";
        }

    private:
        Database* database_;
};

int main() {
    Database db;
    db.name = "Test";

    ConsumeDatabase1 db1{db};
    ConsumeDatabase2 db2{&db};
    ConsumeDatabase3 db3{db};
}
```

Difference between version one and two is, that in Version one i can't pass (that easy) a `nullptr` whereas in Version two it could be allowed, right?

Version one and three are basically the same except, that internally a pointer is stored instead of a reference.

Which Version is better (one or three, if i don't wan't to allow a `nullptr´)? (Or for which use case is one better of the other, as it usully depends on what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Defining better or worse is a bit disputable here. Reference members are generally discouraged (e.g. by C++ core guidelines) as they cannot be easily assigned or moved. Have a look at `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (or its implementation from Boost on older versions of the language) as a rebindable replacement of `T&`. `gsl::not_null` is also a viable option here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may seem like a stylistic preference at first, but there are good reasons for each one of them.
Let's look at all the possibilities:

| Data Member | Constructor Parameter | Summary and Pros & Cons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `&` | `&` | `ConsumeDatabase1`: Simply store a reference. ✔️Obviously correct for non-optional references ✔️Nice syntax (`.` instead of `->`) in member functions ❌Assignment operators are deleted ❌References can't be rebound |
| `*` | `*` | `ConsumeDatabase2`: Accepting a pointer implies that whatever you're referring to is nullable. ✔️Correct for optional references. ✔️Assignment operators and rebinding. ❌Must use `->` inside member functions |
| `&` | `*` | `ConsumeDatabase3`: Same use case as `ConsumeDatabase1`. ✔️Assignment operators and rebinding. ✔️Easily refactored even if the reference becomes optional later. ❌Must use `->` inside member functions. |
| `*` | `&` | Arguably pointless. ✔️Nice syntax (`.` instead of `->`) ❌Assignment operators are deleted ❌References can't be rebound ❌Constructor must throw exceptions if the pointer is nullable. ❌Signature suggests a wide contract, but this exception betrays the user |

Storing a reference is mostly an inferior option to storing a pointer.
It does give you nicer syntax because you can use `.` instead of `->` inside member functions, but otherwise it isn't necessary.

The only remaining questions is whether what you're referring to is optional, or always exists. Use a reference if it isn't optional.

---

*See also: [Should I prefer pointers or references as data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892133/5740428)*

*See also: [When should I use pointers instead of references in API-design?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058339/5740428)*

#### Note on `std::reference_wrapper`

As an alternative to storing pointers, you can also store [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). This basically does the same as storing a pointer, but it communicates more clearly that whatever you're storing isn't nullable.

While it communicates intent more clearly, the class performs very little work for you, and `T*` is obviously more concise than `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. Consider it as an option; I won't recommend you to use it or not to use it, as this is entirely stylistic preference.

---

*See also: [What is the difference between std::reference_wrapper and a simple pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766939/5740428)*

#### Note on lifetimes and storing references

No matter which option you choose, there is the problem that what you're referring to needs to stay alive while `ConsumeDatabase` exists; otherwise, you risk using an object after its lifetime ends.

If this is not trivial to ensure, storing a reference/pointer/etc. may be a bad idea, and a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` may be more appropriate.

---

*See also: [Is it idiomatic to store references members in a class, and are there pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12387239/5740428)*

Answer (score 1):

You're asking in 2023, so I'll answer in 2023. Modern C++ doesn't like raw pointers. They're messy and they don't convey intent well at all. In modern C++, we use our types to convey a notion of *ownership*. That is, the best way to keep track of when to free memory is to make sure we always know who *owns* it. The owner of the memory is responsible for freeing it, and everyone else is simply *borrowing* it for a moment. They didn't create it, and they don't need to destroy it.

You've got two different choices to make here: The type of the instance field and the type of the constructor argument. Let's start with the field. The first question is: Does the class own the `Database` in question? Put another way, when your class instance is freed, should the `Database` also be freed from memory?

## Yes, the Database should be freed

If the answer is yes, you want to stay away from references. If this class is going to be the sole owner of the memory, a scalar `Database` (with no `*` or `&`) is warranted. People tend to get scared when I say the word "scalar", but all that means in this context is "not a pointer or a reference".

In this case, you want a constructor that takes a `Database&&`. That double ampersand is *not* two references: it's an [rvalue reference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299437/what-are-r-value-references-used-for). Basically, if you construct a `ConsumeDatabase` using a `Database&&` constructor, you're *moving* ownership of the constructor and promising that the original value (presumably a local variable in some function somewhere) is never going to be used again.

```
ConsumeDatabase make_consumer() {
  Database my_database(...);
  ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(std::move(my_database));
  ...
  return my_consumer;
}
```

Here, in the `...` section (which might contain some other initialization code), we cannot use `my_database` anymore. The `std::move` signaled our intent to *move* ownership from that variable into `my_consumer`.

If the class `Database` is cheap to copy, you might also provide a `ConsumeDatabase(const Database& database)` constructor which copies the `database` rather than moving it. But databases usually aren't cheap to copy, so that's probably not needed in this case.

**Example:**

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    Database database;
    ConsumeDatabase(Database&& database) : database(database) {}
    // If copying is cheap,
    ConsumeDatabase(const Database& database) : database(database) {}
};

Database some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(std::move(some_database)); // Move
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(some_database); // Copy
```

## Yes, the Database should be freed, and it's virtual

A scalar `Database` is nice, but it has a problem. If `Database` is an open or abstract class, we can't store instances of subclasses in a `Database`. We need a layer of indirection, be it a pointer or a reference.

This is where [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) comes in. An `std::unique_ptr<Database>` is like a `Database*` except that C++ guarantees there's only *one* `std::unique_ptr` to that particular `Database` at a given moment, and the language will automatically free the `Database` when that pointer disappears. Since it's a pointer, it can store subclasses safely, so we can use this if we need virtual dispatch. You can take the unique pointer by value (`std::unique_ptr<Database>`, again with no `&` or `*`), and callers will need to pass it in with `std::move` as before, since we're *moving* ownership to the class.

**Example:**

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    std::unique_ptr<Database> database;
    ConsumeDatabase(std::unique_ptr<Database> database) : database(std::move(database)) {}
};

std::unique_ptr<Database> some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(std::move(some_database));
```

## ConsumeDatabase shares ownership with the caller

Shared ownership is a complicated situation, but it can happen. Maybe several different classes have access to a database, and we need to free the database from memory only once there are *no* other references to it left.

In this case, we use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). `std::shared_ptr` works a lot like `std::unique_ptr` but it can be shared across multiple instances. Since multiple references can exist at a single moment in time, we can cheaply copy an `std::shared_ptr` without copying the underlying data.

**Example:**

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    std::shared_ptr<Database> database;
    ConsumeDatabase(std::shared_ptr<Database> database) : database(database) {}
};

std::shared_ptr<Database> some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(some_database);
```

## ConsumeDatabase is a borrower

But perhaps `ConsumeDatabase` never claims any ownership or exclusive access to the database. In that case, a reference `&` is warranted, as it indicates that we're not remotely responsible for freeing the data. If you use a reference, you as the programmer are responsible for making sure that the *real* owner of the `Database` doesn't get freed too early. If it gets freed before the `ConsumeDatabase` and you try to access the freed memory, that's called a *dangling reference* and is textbook [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

If you need to be able to mutate the `Database`, take a `Database&`. If not, take a `const Database&`. In either case, the constructor argument should match the field.

**Example:** (immutable)

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    const Database& database;
    ConsumeDatabase(const Database& database) : database(database) {}
};

Database some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(some_database);
```

**Example:** (mutable)

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    Database& database;
    ConsumeDatabase(Database& database) : database(database) {}
};

Database some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(some_database);
```

## It's complicated ...

Okay, but we live in a complicated world. If none of the above cases apply and the owner of the database is truly really messy and complicated, that's where a raw pointer comes in. Take a `Database*`, store it in a field of type `Database*`, and *heavily* document why it is the way it is, and how long that memory is expected to live.

Think *very* hard before you go this way. There are very few reasons to use a raw pointer in modern C++, but I'll never say "never".

For a bit of context, my last major C++ project consisted of just over 30,000 lines of code. There is exactly *one* class that uses a raw pointer in that codebase. Exactly *one* time did I resort to this failsafe option. It was to implement a hot path of code more efficiently and couldn't be expressed with the above, and I left *paragraphs* of explanation as to why and how to use that class. This is the last resort option.

**Example:**

```
class ConsumeDatabase {
    Database* database;
    ConsumeDatabase(Database* database) : database(database) {}
};

Database* some_database;
ConsumeDatabase my_consumer(some_database);
```

Comment: Telling people to *never* use raw pointers is uninformed and goes against the consensus of the C++ community. There are numerous additions to the C++ standard library in recent years, such as `std::start_lifetime_as<T>(void*)` in C++23, `std::construct_at(T*)` in C++20, or `std::is_within_lifetime(const T*)` in C++26. See also [CppCoreGuidelines F.7: For general use, take `T*` or `T&` arguments rather than smart pointers](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-smart).

Comment: There is consensus on [I.11: Never transfer ownership by a raw pointer (`T*`) or reference (`T&`)](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-raw), and if this advice is followed, then there isn't any significant problem with raw pointers. Raw pointers are modern and idiomatic, not a "last resort".

Answer (score 0):

Storing a reference (being as pointer or reference) is not necessarily a bad idea, but risky.

You never know, when the reference gets destroyed.
Well not quite, as the user Martin York pointed it out in the comment section below: *"The rules of object destruction are deterministic and well-defined. But sometimes the relationship of the two object is non trivial."*

A safe solution would be to copy (even move) the reference. Since some objects are very heavyweight, an internal shared object could be used.

e.g.

```
struct Database {
    struct info { /*all relevant data here*/ };
    std::shared_ptr<info> m_info;
};

struct ConsumeDatabase {
    // if database goes out of scope (destroyed),
    // each access within this object is still safe (database is still referenced)
    // -> last one turns off the lights
    ConsumeDatabase(const Database& database) : m_db{database} {}
    Database m_db; //solid storage, keeps the database alive
};
```

Comment: @MartinYork I've borrowed your statement, hope that's ok with you.

Comment: No problems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### ConsumeDatabase1:

Pass and store a reference.
Perfectly valid. Great for simple locally and easy to write.

Downside: You can't copy it.

#### ConsumeDatabase2:

Pass and store a pointer.
Perfectly valid. You should only use this if you want the ability to have a `nullptr` in the database. Which means the code gets complicated with a bunch of extra checks.

Downside: Extra code for validation everywhere.

#### ConsumeDatabase3:

Perfectly valid. Gets around the copying problem of version1.

Downside: More unit tests to validate that you don't accidentally put a null pointer into the object after the code is updated (You have to think about about the next person messing up your code).

#### std::reference_wrapper

Another alternative is `std::reference_wrapper`

```
class ConsumeDatabase4
{
    public:
        ConsumeDatabase4(Database& database): database_{database} {
            std::cout << &database << "\n";
        }

    private:
        std::reference_wrapper<Database> database_;
};
```

Like `ConsumeDatabase1` but without the disadvantage.

#### Which to use?

If I need a `nullable` database then `consumeDatabase2` is your only options. But with a little work you could have the concept of and empty database so you don't need a `nullable` database. So this is my least likely choice.

In most situations, it would be `consumeDatabase1`. If you simply need the wrapper in local scope and don't start passing things around by value.

If you need to pass things around by value, then `consumeDatabase3` or `consumeDatabase4` are both valid and will depend on the context. Is this an internal class (consumeDatabase3 probably) is this class going beyond my local interface out to another system (consumeDatabase4 possibly). It all really depends on how much testing and maintenance I expect on the class.

If there is something complex in lifetimes then maybe you need to look at other options (including dynamic creation).