# How can I update a value in an object i passed by reference and have that reference update with it

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dependencies

This seems like a fundamental understanding of software design patterns that i should and do not understand already however i am okay with that because for the most part i am self taught

let me give an example of what i am trying to accomplish

```
class obj1 {
 private:
   int val;

 public:
    obj1() {}
    int getVal() { return this->val;}
    void setThatCondition(int thatCondition) {this->val = thatCondition;}
}

class obj2 {
 private:
    obj1 o;

 public:
    obj2(obj1 &o1) {
       this->o = o1;
    }

    void lookForUpdate() {

       while (this->o.getVal() != `some condition`) {
           do a thing
       }
    }
}

int main() {
  obj1 ob1;
  obj2 ob2(ob1);


  ob2.lookForUpdate();

  ob1.setThatCondition(`whateverCondition`);

}
```

UPDATE/ANSWER AS I UNDERSTAND IT:

1: i am passing in  a reference incorrectly (less confident in this bulletpoint)

2: I am assigning that reference in correctly

#2 makes sense to me and if i am right than i am no longer "Tracking" that object. I have lost my reference

in object 1 i have a value that changes arbitrarily
in object 2 i have a while loop that behaves conditionally on a value in  object 1 that i update after i have already passed in by reference

what i want to happen is for lookForUpdate to be notified but what i think im finding is that i already passed in the value so the while loop doesn't get the change

this seems like something fundamental i dont quite understand yet

What am i missing please

Comment: `obj1 o;` is not a reference.

Comment: please post real code. Instead of ```some condition``` just put some condition

Comment: updating now
i was trying to be concise because the real code is far more layered

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I think you basically want to know [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

Comment: Your edited/updated code is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `this->o = o1;` -- C++ is not java.  `this->o` and `o1` are two separate objects.

Comment: *"How can I update a value in an object i passed by reference..."* **Make the data member `o` a reference?** [Is it idiomatic to store references members in a class, and are there pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387239/is-it-idiomatic-to-store-references-members-in-a-class-and-are-there-pitfalls)

Comment: 1) `int axis = NULL;` -- What is the goal here?  Why are you assigning NULL to an `int`?
2) `catch (exception e)` -- This looks like another java-ism.  If `e` is an object, then exceptions are usually caught by reference.

Comment: 1: I thought i understood what the diff is between ref and val
confirmation--
ref=reference to the original object--
val=copy of the value but not actually linked to the object--

2: @PaulMcKenzie can you explain more please

3: what information are you missing for a minimal code to reproduce
   i have how its called, how its instantiated, and how its updated
   what can  i offer more to clarify

 everyone thank you so  far

Comment: When i read how to pass by reference it basically put the & operator infront of the parameter and send it in

Comment: i can assign a -1 to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Explain in your own words what is happening when you do this: `this->o = o1;`.  The reason why I mentioned java is that lines of code that looks like this in Java mean something totally diffferent than what is meant in C++.  To be honest, it looks like you're trying to leverage what you know in Java when writing C++ code.  Don't do this, as that will just make things more confusing for you.

Comment: thank you it is my goal to store a reference of the changing object in the observing object so that when the changing object is updated the observing object while know regardless of when
@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @TheThinkrium Just change  `obj1 o;` to `obj1 &o;`. That is why I added the first [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387239/is-it-idiomatic-to-store-references-members-in-a-class-and-are-there-pitfalls). Also when you do make the change, don't forget that you will have to initialize `o` in initializer list.

Comment: @TheThinkrium `this->o = o1;` -- You assigned an object to another object.  They are two separate objects.  When that line of code is completed, `this->o` and `o1` have gone their separate ways.  They are not "linked together" like they would be in Java.

Comment: okay to confirm-- it is possible that i am doing java stuff with c++ and i am not assigning correctly

I will update the question with the answer as i understand it and double plus thank you for everyones clarification

Comment: *What am i missing please* What Java calls a "reference", C++ calls a "pointer".  What C++ calls a "reference" has no equivalent in Java.