# Why is it "dumb to override the & operator and return *this*"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Granted, I cannot think of any reason why I would ever **want** to override the unary `&` operator, but in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4542813/368896 the poster states, in regards to some class `X`:

> ...unless X does something really dumb, like overloading the unary &
>   to return this

(NOTE: I assume this comment refers to the fact of the `&` operator returning `this`, not the fact of overriding the `&` operator itself.)

As I thought about that comment, it occurred to me that "returning this" is *exactly* what the `&` operator does - even in cases of multiple inheritance.

Given that one might never *want* to override the unary `&` operator, nonetheless why would it be dumb to have it return `this` (if you did decide to override it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it occurred to me that "returning this" is exactly what the & operator does

You're right about that, although C++ also **forbids taking the address of a temporary object**.

In the context of [the question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542789), which is about determining if an object is a temporary:

If you implement your own `operator &` that returns `this`, you will bypass this protection by telling the compiler that `&(expression)` is always valid. Consider:

```
struct foo
{
};

struct bar
{
    bar* operator&()
    {
        return this;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void test(const T*)
{
    // no temporaries, can't take address of temporary...right?
}

int main()
{
    foo x;
    test(&x); // okay, x is an lvalue

    /*
    test(&(foo())); // not okay, cannot take address of temporary
    */

    bar y;
    test(&y); // still okay, y is an lvalue

    test(&(bar())); // huh?! not taking address of temporary, calling operator&
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, so I added the sample code I had written. Edit as you like.

Answer (score 2):

**It indeed has very limited uses.**
One usecase for example are smartpointers as they are often used in Direct3D to wrap `IUnknown` objects.

I assume you're not familiar with Direct3D, so I'll talk a bit more on that.
Many Direct3D classes derive from [`IUnknown`](http://doc.51windows.net/Directx9_SDK/?url=/directx9_sdk/intro/program/com/iunknown_interface.htm) and after they've been used one must call `Release`. Yep, D3D internally uses reference counting. People tend to forget calling `Release` and it really is very tedious. So what one does is wrapping the `IUnknown` into a `smartpointer` which will do the release behind the scenes.

```
smart_pointer<ID3D11Device> device = // ..
```

Thus, by stating `&device` you don't want the address of `smart_pointer<ID3D11Device>`, you want the address of `ID3D11Device`.

```
template <class T>
class com_ptr
{
private:
    T *inst;

public:
   // many other methods/overloadings

    T** operator & ()
    {
        return &inst;
    }
};
```

**Bottom line:** This way, you can invoke `Release` in the destructor and don't have to care about it in the rest of the code.

**Bottom line 2:** The better way to do it is to add a `get()` method which returns the intern object.

```
    T** get()
    {
        return &inst;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how using a smart pointer entails overloading `operator&`.

Comment: yes, we can get many examples of using smart pointers: boost, QuantLib i.e., but please refer closer to overloading &

Comment: @cf16,@GManNickG added an example

Comment: Still looks pretty dumb to me.

Comment: -1, this is known to be terrible design. This is why we add `get()` member functions to smart pointers and leave the pointers themselves alone. It's code like this that made us have to add `std::addressof`!

Comment: @GManNickG It isn't my code, but it explains a usecase. So please remove the downvote. I'll add a hint to that.

Comment: It's not a use case though, since there is absolutely no reason to do it.  Overload `operator*` and `operator->` so your smart pointer behaves like a regular pointer, you don't need to overload `operator&`.

Comment: @poitroae: But you say at the top it's not dumb design and then give an example. :)

Comment: Does Direct3D have a class that overrides the `&` operator this way?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum No, the "smart pointer" (often called ComPointer here) is a class you have to write on your own (or find on the web).